# Volumetric Lighting help

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, volumetrics

I'm trying to render out an image with light emitting from an object, but I am very new to Cycles.

How can I achieve an effect like this easily?

[image]

It's only for a single frame, so it can be a simple fake to look like that. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind! I solved it! I had to put cones jutting out with some shaders applied, and point lamps behind them. See some of the other volumetric lighting questions for the nodes to use!

Comment: Please expand on your answer so that if other people have the same issue they can solve it by following steps in your answer.